# Poles of a function involing Gamma- and Beta function

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

I am interested in the poles of following function of $s$ where $0\leq x\leq1$ and $0\leq \delta < \infty$:

$$M(s) = \frac{B(x;\delta+s-1,\delta)}{ \frac{\Gamma(2\delta)}{2 \Gamma(\delta)^2} +
\frac{\Gamma(\delta+s-1)\Gamma(\delta) }{\Gamma(2\delta +s -1)} - B(x;\delta+s-1,\delta)}$$

where $B$ is the [incomplete Beta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Incomplete_beta_function) and $\Gamma$ the [Gamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function). I have the feeling that the poles are at $1-\delta$ but have no idea how to show that. I know that the Gamma function has simple poles at ${0,-1,-2,\dots}$ but what about the (incomplete) Beta function?

**EDIT**

I thought a bit more about it. As a first step  knowing the value (or even existence) of the following limit would help me a lot

$$ \lim_{s\rightarrow -k} \frac{\Gamma{(s)}}{B(x;s;\delta)} $$

for $k=0,1,2,\dots$ and $0<x < 1$ and $\delta>0$

Many thanks.